# How to guarantee the minimum path removed from priority queue is the shortest path after all infinite vertices relaxed

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I readed the proof of Dijkstra's algorithm in "CLRS"，and the code in Algorithms, 4th Edition by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne. Figure 24.7 in CLRS proofs the correctness of Dijkstra's algorithm.

- The proof said that we should add the minimum path vertex in set `V - S`,
- But the code add the minimum path vertex in priority queue to SPT.

My question is how to guarantee the vertices that not be relaxed currently (which `distTo` is `POSITIVE_INFINITY`) will never shorter than the removed  minimum vertex after the following loop.

In another word, should we consider the vertices that not be relaxed currently when we remove the minimum path vertex from set `V - S`?

Forgive my English, please.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You seem to be saying, "How do we know the algorithm works?" but that's what the proof you're reading is supposed to prove. The key point is that you're removing the closest vertex (say, $x$) so any other vertex $y$ must be at least as far away, and any path to $x$ through $y$ must be at least as long as the path to $y$.

Comment: @david-richerby is there any possible, when I remove a vertex `x`, there is another vertex `y` not be relaxed yet, and `distTo[y] = POSITIVE_INFINITY`, but after vertex `x` is removed, `distTo[y]` is relaxed less than `distTo[x]`?

Comment: No because, if the distance to $y$ was less than the distance to $x$, then $y$ would have been relaxed before $x$. I suggest you go slowly and carefully through the proof: the details aren't easy but it does actually work.

Comment: @david-richerby  thanks any way